# Configure Let's Encrypt in Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, lets-encrypt, azure-container-service, azure-container-instances

We have an AspNetCore WebAPI and an WebApp deployed in a couple of Azure Container Instances, and need to configure the HTTPS for both.
Right now (in development) we use self-sign certificates (.pfx) that are loaded on startup from a path in the container.

We are interested in using Let's Encrypt certificates but in my research I can't find a way to configure Let's Encrypt using Azure Container Instances. I can only find ways to configure Azure App Service and projects hosted in VMs.

Does anyone know of any way to do this configuration? Or some example that even if it is not identical, I can base it to make this configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can just add the certificates to Azure Container Instances. There no way to do that as I know. But you can go around a bend to achieve this. Create an internal Azure Container Instances and associate an Application Gateway with it, then you can add your certificates to the Application gateway.

Comment: Any update? Or you solve the problem?

Comment: I'm just thinking if it would be possible to mount an Azure File share as a volume to a container.  That fileshare should then contain the certificates.  Don't know if it's possible to do that